# Type Hints in abstract class

Tags: php, abstract-class, type-hinting

Prior to PHP 7.2 the following generates a nice `Fatal Error`

```
abstract class A {
    abstract protected function meth(int $var);
}

class B extends A {
    public function meth($var) {
        return $var;
    }
}

$b = new B;
echo $b->meth(33.3); // Fatal error:  Declaration of B::meth($var) must be compatible with A::meth(int $var) in [...][...]on line [..]
```

But as of PHP 7.2 this will output `33.3` unless I type hint `$var` parameter in `meth` in class B to a different data type let's say `float` then it will generate our nice `fatal error`.

```
class B extends A {
    public function meth(float $var) { // Type hint added
        return $var;
    }
}
$b = new B;
echo $b->meth(33.3); //// Fatal error:  Declaration of B::meth($var) must be compatible with A::meth(int $var) in [...][...]on line [..]
```

My question is :

Did class `B` inherit the type hint (int in our case) of meth method in class A automatically ? if so, shouldn't be the output `33` rather than `33.3`?

Comment: In your first example, you don't get an error as your essentially removing the hint, you can see that here https://3v4l.org/CLLHD, you get it in the second because you're changing its type, which is not allowed.. apparently.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone According to php.net on Class Abstraction  " The signatures of the methods must match, i.e. the type hints and the number of required arguments must be the same" so prior to PHP 7.2 the fatal error actually makes sense.

Comment: Looking at the changes its because of [Parameter Type Widening](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/parameter-no-type-variance)